# SQL: SELECT the inverse of a query

Tags: sql

I have this query and I'd like to *select the **inverse** of this query* (the ones which are not concerned.

```
SELECT*
FROM input1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(Ref) AS Ref, Nomlatin, Lieudit, Commune
    FROM input1
    GROUP BY Nomlatin, Lieudit, Commune
) as t1 
ON input1.Ref = t1.Ref
WHERE t1.Ref IS NULL
```

I have already searched for answers to this question but I didn't succeed to use the `NOT IN`.

If someone can help me, it would be great.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean of "the inverse"?  Which SQL engine (SQL Server, MySQL, ...)?

Comment: Sample data will help

Comment: What about IS NOT NULL

Comment: Change outer to inner join may be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have your `WHERE` clause at the end that filters everything in the final result set that `IS NULL`.

The "inverse" or opposite of that would be returned if you would replace `IS NULL` with `IS NOT NULL`.

```
SELECT*
FROM input1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(Ref) AS Ref, Nomlatin, Lieudit, Commune
    FROM input1
    GROUP BY Nomlatin, Lieudit, Commune
) as t1 
ON input1.Ref = t1.Ref
WHERE t1.Ref IS NOT NULL -- minor change here
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with *correlated* `subquery` :

```
SELECT i.*
FROM input1 i
WHERE Ref = (SELECT MAX(i1.Ref) 
             FROM input1 i1 
             WHERE i1.Nomlatin = i.Nomlatin AND i1.Lieudit = i.Lieudit, i1.Commune = i.Commune
            );
```